# Garage door buttons on car to control RPi

Tags: home-automation

Is it possible to capture a button press from the universal garage remote that is  built into my car? id like to use this in my  project to turn on porch light and unlock the door. do I need some kind of RF sensor or am i just dreaming

Comment: I suppose it must be possible: it can control the garage door, so as a worst case you could take the door controller apart, find how it actuates the motor and piggy-back off that.  Perhaps there's a more elegant solution.  If you tell us more about the universal controller in your car (make, model etc.) someone may know something.

Comment: If it's a 433MHz transmitter then [something like this](https://energenie4u.co.uk/catalogue/product/ENER314-RT) should pick up the signals

Answer (score -1):

No, you are not dreaming.  You can use Rpi/RpiZW/ESP8266 for WiFi control.  You can use your smart phone to "press" a button.

You can DIY the following open garage project.

[Introducing OpenGarage: an Open-Source WiFi Garage Door Opener using ESP8266 - 53,471 views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpwEa_48-Cw)

[image: Open garage project]

***Update 2019apr07hkt1343***

The above answer is too brief.  I should have suggested that more relays can be added to control porch light and solenoid door lock.

[image: open garage opener extended to control porch light and solenoid door lock]

[AliExpress DC 6V/12V Electromagnetic Solenoid Door Lock - US$2](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/Hot-Sale-Mini-DC-6V-12V-Electric-solenoid-Lock-small-electromagnetic-lock-Cabinet-Door-Electric-Lock/32845944388.html?spm=a2g0w.10010108.1000016.1.2b927455NGbpwh&isOrigTitle=true)

[image: Door dock]

Comment: That seems to be an answer to a different question. The OP wants to control it from the universal remote built into his car, not from his phone.

Comment: I agree. I should have said that remote RF garage opener built into the car cannot be easily modified to control extra things like porch light and door lock. A way to get around is to use a Wifi controller such as ESP8266 or RpiZeroWifi.